# Receiving http requests using tcp Winsock cpp/c

Tags: c, http, server, winsock

I'm new to using Winsock for http protocol (only used it with a custom protocol that I made) so please bare with me.

I want to create a server that receives http requests that I will send to it with Libcurl(I've seen that it supports external sockets), but I don't know in what format it sends it.. is it just a plain string? or jason?
It is important to me as I need to create a RequestHandler that will be able to extract the type of http method and the data (if its a POST method) and act upon it (add users to DB/remove etc..).
I decided to use HTTP so I could in the future turn it into https.

My assumption is that it sends it in 1 string like this:
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"

Help will be gladly appreciated!

Here is the Libcurl code if you are intrested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#define close closesocket
#else
#include <sys/types.h>        /*  socket types              */
#include <sys/socket.h>       /*  socket definitions        */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>        /*  inet (3) functions         */
#include <unistd.h>           /*  misc. Unix functions      */
#endif
 
#include <errno.h>
 
/* The IP address and port number to connect to */
#define IPADDR "127.0.0.1"
#define PORTNUM 80
 
#ifndef INADDR_NONE
#define INADDR_NONE 0xffffffff
#endif
 
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
  return written;
}
 
static int closecb(void *clientp, curl_socket_t item)
{
  (void)clientp;
  printf("libcurl wants to close %d now\n", (int)item);
  return 0;
}
 
static curl_socket_t opensocket(void *clientp,
                                curlsocktype purpose,
                                struct curl_sockaddr *address)
{
  curl_socket_t sockfd;
  (void)purpose;
  (void)address;
  sockfd = *(curl_socket_t *)clientp;
  /* the actual externally set socket is passed in via the OPENSOCKETDATA
     option */
  return sockfd;
}
 
static int sockopt_callback(void *clientp, curl_socket_t curlfd,
                            curlsocktype purpose)
{
  (void)clientp;
  (void)curlfd;
  (void)purpose;
  /* This return code was added in libcurl 7.21.5 */
  return CURL_SOCKOPT_ALREADY_CONNECTED;
}
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;  /*  socket address structure  */
  curl_socket_t sockfd;
 
#ifdef WIN32
  WSADATA wsaData;
  int initwsa = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
  if(initwsa) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", initwsa);
    return 1;
  }
#endif
 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /*
     * Note that libcurl will internally think that you connect to the host
     * and port that you specify in the URL option.
     */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://99.99.99.99:9999");
 
    /* Create the socket "manually" */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == CURL_SOCKET_BAD) {
      printf("Error creating listening socket.\n");
      return 3;
    }
 
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port   = htons(PORTNUM);
 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPADDR);
    if(INADDR_NONE == servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr) {
      close(sockfd);
      return 2;
    }
 
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) ==
       -1) {
      close(sockfd);
      printf("client error: connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return 1;
    }
 
    /* no progress meter please */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
 
    /* send all data to this function  */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
 
    /* call this function to get a socket */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, opensocket);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA, &sockfd);
 
    /* call this function to close sockets */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION, closecb);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA, &sockfd);
 
    /* call this function to set options for the socket */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION, sockopt_callback);
 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
 
    close(sockfd);
 
    if(res) {
      printf("libcurl error: %d\n", res);
      return 4;
    }
  }
 
#ifdef WIN32
  WSACleanup();
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what code is sending the request; the protocol is the same regardless, and the request is a sequence of octets. Consider reading at least an [overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP/1.1_request_messages). And do use a library, like most people.

Comment: @molbdnilo do you have a library you recommend?

Comment: https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#networking has plenty of options to consider.